How to test migration from native android app to flutter app?
I am migrating a native Android app to Flutter. I've rewritten the app from scratch in flutter, and I'd like to test upgrading from the Android app to the Flutter app (I want to make sure the Flutter app can read and correctly handle the locally stored data from the Android app.)
If I uninstall the old, native version, I am able to launch the new version just fine. However, if I try to install the new version with the old version installed, it launches the OLD version and just hangs forever in the console with the following output. It never launches the new version of the app.
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.

The Flutter app has the same application id as the Android app but a newer version code. This behavior happens on both a real device and the emulator.
Please don't tell me to uninstall the old version; that would defeat the purpose of this test! Any other ideas or even just suggestions on how to debug this would be appreciated.

The new version probably have a different signing key so it won't install. Make sure to sign the build with the same signing key.

I updated the signing information to be consistent, but I am still getting the same behavior.
Do you know if there's any way to get more information from the installation process? It would be so helpful to see why it's stopping!

Have you updated the versionCode in the new app so that it is not smaller than the old one?

please share further logs from the console. it must be saying something like this: installation complete or failed or incompatible?

Ricky, yes. And Jain, no, unfortunately, it just hangs forever, which is a big part of my struggle.

I still don't know what the real problem is, but I was able to install the flutter app using adb:
adb install -d build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk
Once that is installed, I can then launch the flutter app normally (in debug mode on VS Code) and test/debug the migration.
A little clunky, but it'll work for my purpose.
Thanks for the help!
